# Show suggestion on focus using PrimeNG autocomplete component

Tags: angular, primeng

I would make autocomplete showing suggestion when user click on input field.

For the moment suggestions are showed only if user enter characters.

```
<p-autoComplete [formControl]="control.controls.EJ_Id_Name" 
  [suggestions]="results" 
  (completeMethod)="search($event,'EJ')" 
  emptyMessage={{noResult}} 
  [autoHighlight]="true">
</p-autoComplete>
```

I have tried to add `(onFocus)` and pass to it `search($event,'EJ')`

Here's my search function :

```
search(event, type) {
    this.searchRmpmService.getResults(event.query, type).then(data => {
        console.log(event);
        if(event.query){
            this.results = this.filterResults(event.query, data);
            console.log(this.results)
        }
        else {

            this.results = ["onfocus"];
            console.log(this.results) // I get "onfocus" on my devtool browser when I focus on the input            }

    });
}
```

`onFocus()` does not show me a suggestion list, I guess that I should call `(completeMethod)` in `onFocus`   but I don't know how ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may help if you need additionally to display suggestion when the input field of autocomplete is cleared. Therefore 2 events will be handled: `onFocus` and `onClear`. Here is the workaround:

In template bind `onClear` event with function `clearItem()`:

```
<p-autoComplete ...
    #autocomplete
    (onFocus)="!autocomplete.value && autocomplete.handleDropdownClick()"
    (onClear)="clearItem(autocomplete)">
</p-autoComplete>
```

In component implement function `clearItem()` when `onClear` event is triggered:

```
clearItem(autocomplete: any) {
    autocomplete.value = '';  
    autocomplete.handleDropdownClick();  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The autocomplete has the `onFocus()` event, you can show the suggestions by calling the `.show()` method.

```
<p-autoComplete  #autoComplete [formControl]="control.controls.EJ_Id_Name" 
  (onFocus)="autoComplete.show()"
  [suggestions]="results" 
  (completeMethod)="search($event,'EJ')" 
  emptyMessage={{noResult}} 
  [autoHighlight]="true">
</p-autoComplete>
```

**Edit:**

It seems like there a bug with the autocomplete, as a workaround you can try this

```
<p-autoComplete  #autoComplete [formControl]="control.controls.EJ_Id_Name" 
  (onFocus)="!autocomplete.value && autocomplete.handleDropdownClick()"
  [suggestions]="results" 
  (completeMethod)="search($event,'EJ')" 
  emptyMessage={{noResult}} 
  [autoHighlight]="true">
</p-autoComplete>
```

[Source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3976#issuecomment-368755441)

Comment: That works but I get an empty rectangle. How can I pass to `show()` method the values ?

Comment: I have a little problem is when I select a value the suggestion panel still visible

Comment: I got the solution : add `(onFocus)="!autocomplete.value && autocomplete.handleDropdownClick()"`

Comment: can we please post angular & package versions ??? had to hunt quite a bit for that info.. thanks

Comment: What worked for me is calling this.autocomplete.hide(); and then this.autocomplete.show();